# CurrentProject vs CurrentDb

Tags: sql, vba

I'm new to VBA and very new to SQL so I don't quite understand why I am having this problem. I'm trying to import excel files into an access database. For a few reasons I have to store my excel data into an array and then upload that array into a temporary table and then append the pertinent parts of the table. To my current understanding, the best way to get my data from my array into a new temporary table would be to create that table and then populate it row by row using SQL. My problem is that when I try to create the table, I get an error. I've simplified my code, I believe this contains what you need to know.

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "CREATE TABLE TestTable (`Value` VARCHAR(20))"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

This works fine

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "CREATE TABLE TestTable (`Value` DECIMAL(4,2))"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

This results in run-time error 3292 "Syntax error in field definition"

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "CREATE TABLE TestTable (`Value` DECIMAL(4,2))"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
```

This works fine

Is there a reason why I should ever use one over the other? Simply changing to CurrentProject seems to fix any problems I have but I just want to understand what is happening here. I have done my own research but any answer I find goes over my head (again, I am relatively new to VBA). I apologize in advance, there may be no answer that I am currently able to comprehend

Comment: Not sure of your specific problem, but you can avoid creating the table by having a temporary table pre-made that you just empty before populating with data from Excel (`DELETE * FROM TestTable`).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `CurrentDb.Execute` supports a different ANSI SQL standard, I think ANSI 89, although I could be wrong. `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` supports ANSI 92, which allows that statement to execute correctly. It's a different spec of the SQL language. If you've ever used or will use SQL server this becomes obvious pretty quickly.

You should notice that your SQL statement won't work either trying to run it as a plain SQL query either. To run this successfully as a query, one option is to enable ANSI 92 as it isn't enabled by default in Access. See below for the relevant option to toggle.

[image: Setting in Access for ANSI 92]

That being said, changing the SQL standard may be less than ideal if you are familiar with Access' SQL syntax, however it might be very helpful if you already have experience with SQL Server. Also worth noting, changing the ANSI option in Access won't change how `CurrentDB.Execute` runs executes SQL statements in VBA, you'll still need the current approach, or running a stored query.